# Why is numpy's behavior different if I slice out only 1 column vs. if I slice out multiple columns?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

If I have a numpy array called data, for example:

```
[[  3.6216    8.6661   -2.8073   -0.44699   0.     ]
[  4.5459    8.1674   -2.4586   -1.4621    0.     ]
[  3.866    -2.6383    1.9242    0.10645   0.     ]]
```

and I want to get the last column, I can slice it out by doing:

```
data[:,4]
```

However, the output gets "flattened" automatically:

```
[0. 0. 0]
```

My expectation was that it should be giving me this instead:

```
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

I know I can easily reshape this, but I would like to understand why numpy is flattening this automatically when I select ONE column. If I select multiple columns instead:

```
data[:,:4]
```

I get what I expect:

```
[[  3.6216    8.6661   -2.8073   -0.44699]
 [  4.5459    8.1674   -2.4586   -1.4621 ]
 [  3.866    -2.6383    1.9242    0.10645]]
```

**Why is numpy's behavior different if I slice out only 1 column vs. if I slice out multiple columns? Is there any way to make numpy's behavior for slicing out 1 column NOT flatten the array?**

Comment: `print(data[:,4:5])` ?

Comment: Why is python's behavior different with lists?  For both indexing with a scalar removes a layer/dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you index using a single number, the dimension is eliminated.  That's just how NumPy is designed.  So this:

```
data[:,4]
```

Means "Give me column 4, and reduce the number of dimensions by 1."  Whereas this:

```
data[:,4:5]
```

Means "Give me column 4, but keep the number of dimensions unchanged."

Comment: Wow. Did not know "4" and "4:5" meant different things. Thanks.